NUnit: Mock setup fails if method is setup with actual argument
I have a setup defined like this
Mock<IDeclarationQuery> _declarationQueryMock = new Mock<IDeclarationQuery>();

_declarationQueryMock.Setup(x => x.FindDeclarationDetailAsync(It.IsAny<FindDeclarationModel>(), cancellationToken))
        .ReturnsAsync(declarationDetailResponse);

And it works perfectly. I get the declarationDetailResponse when the test tries to run this method.
In this setup I am passing the random object of FindDeclarationModel to the argument using It.IsAny<FindDeclarationModel>().
Then I thought to make it even more specific. So I tried passing the actual argument to the method in the setup that the test is actually going to get while running. So I tried this
FindDeclarationModel findDeclarationModel = new FindDeclarationModel()
{
    CountryCode = "AFG",
    DeclarationTypeId = DeclarationTypes.ADPA,
    Year = 2022
};

_declarationQueryMock.Setup(x => x.FindDeclarationDetailAsync(findDeclarationModel, cancellationToken))
    .ReturnsAsync(declarationDetailResponse);

But then it stops working.
From stop working I mean that the FindDeclarationDetailAsync then starts returning null when the test runs.
While I made sure and even checked during debugging that the method is getting called with the exact same structured and valued object of FindDeclarationModel which I am passing in the setup, but still it stops working.
Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible?
Is it trying to match the actual and setup object by reference and so considering them different?

what is FindDeclarationDetailAsync? Chances are, the actual method is used, because the method isn't marked abstract or virtual.

btw.: it's very unlikly, that the method is executed with that exact object provided to the mock, but instead with something with equal properties. This however won't make it equal regarding the argument-matching.

How can the actual method is used if I am giving a setup for it from the mock repository? I do not see any possibility of the actual method getting called. Also, the setup does work when I provide the random object of FindDeclarationModel which means the setup is working

well, you didn't provide what _declarationQuery is, so I just guessed.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I totally got the reason of your confusion. It was my bad. I updated the question with the detail :)

In your setup, you expect any object of type FindDeclarationModel:
_declarationQuery.Setup(x => x.FindDeclarationDetailAsync(It.IsAny<FindDeclarationModel>(), cancellationToken))
    .ReturnsAsync(declarationDetailResponse);

The Moq compares the objects by references, meaning you might not pass your exact instance of FindDeclarationModel.
You might probably map the FindDeclarationModel inside method you test but no passing it as is in this method.
As a quick solution, you could use the next setup:
_declarationQuery.Setup(x => x.FindDeclarationDetailAsync(
        It.Is<FindDeclarationModel>(f => f.CountryCode == findDeclarationModel.CountryCode &&
                                         f.DeclarationTypeId == findDeclarationModel.DeclarationTypeId &&
                                         f.Year == findDeclarationModel.Year), 
        cancellationToken))
    .ReturnsAsync(declarationDetailResponse);

You might also handle your comparison by using .Callback:
_declarationQuery.Setup(x => x.FindDeclarationDetailAsync(
        It.IsAny<FindDeclarationModel>(), 
        cancellationToken))
    .Callback((FindDeclarationModel model, CancellationToken token) =>
    {
        // you can get access to model here for comparing
    })
    .ReturnsAsync(declarationDetailResponse);


That is an amazing solution!! The It.Is<> part worked exactly the way I want. Thank you very much! Marked the answer as correct and upvoted also :)
